# Bootstrap navigation issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Alright so Im quite new to Bootstrap, I've been doing some coding and Ive stumbled upon an issue with my navigation in mobile.

No matter what I do, the navigation on mobile seems to fall apart once you click the 3 bars button...

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Media Company</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hire us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

sample code
https://jsfiddle.net/ed8o8vuz/

Comment: Can you post some screenshots?

Comment: Define "*fall apart*". Your code works [**perfectly fine**](https://jsfiddle.net/5dyyshhm/) (assuming you are using valid Bootstrap & jQuery links). Please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including your references to both Bootstrap and jQuery.

Comment: Edit your question and in your code snippet post the HTML for the entire page including all of the css and javascript links you have in there.

Comment: Heres the example of what I mean, ill update the OP
https://jsfiddle.net/ed8o8vuz/

Comment: @Tommy, this works as expected. Also I have opened your jsfiddle in my mobile phone.

Comment: Since Bootstrap 4 was just officially released, you should probably indicate what version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are expecting. If not, please comment a little more on the problem.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Media Company</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hire us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are presenting to us is because the menu is inside the bar? You want it to go below? If so, remove the last `</div>` before the closing `</header>` tag and place it below the closing `</button>` tag.

See the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/ed8o8vuz/1/

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Media Company</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"><span class="icon-bar">
                  
                </span>
                <span class="icon-bar">
                  
                </span>
                <span class="icon-bar">
                  
                </span>
                </button>
  </div>

  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hire us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

If you feel that the navbar-collapse needs to be inside a container, you can simply create a div with the container class and your code will look like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/ed8o8vuz/2/

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Media Company</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"><span class="icon-bar">
                      
                    </span>
                    <span class="icon-bar">
                      
                    </span>
                    <span class="icon-bar">
                      
                    </span>
                    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">


    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hire us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Both solutions work and basically achieve the same result.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Its because you forgot the navbar header class that should wrap the navbar toggle button and the navbar brand in bootstrap 3 so it should look like the following:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Media Company</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hire us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```